# Deferred rendering how to exclude meshes from light contribution

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, qt3d

I've set up a deferred rendering pipeline using Qt3D. So far so good, but now I'd like to add selection boxes around the meshes rendered in the scene.

Unfortunately, the selection box mesh is affected by lights and I don't want that (See **"shaded"** picture below). For example I might want to set the ambient light intensity to 0 and the selection boxes should still be visible. Another example is if I want to show the typical X/Y/Z indicator in one of the viewport corners.

I've got the typical light pass shader for light contribution calculation, which is (in short) this:

```
void main()
{
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / winSize;
    vec4 col = texture(color, texCoord);
    vec3 pos = texture(position, texCoord).xyz;
    vec3 norm = texture(normal, texCoord).xyz;
    ... calculate lights contribution...
    fragColor = vec4(col.rgb * lightColor, col.a);
}
```

If I replace the fragColor line with:

```
fragColor = vec4(col.rgb, col.a);
```

I get the **non shaded** picture below, which shows the color I'd want for the selection box.

Is there any trick or common practice to exclude specific meshes from the light pass ?

I already tried to "trick" the shader with special values like color alpha = 0.123 but it doesn't help at all.

**Shaded**

[image]

**Non shaded**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Store somewhere in the gbuffer when a pixel should not be lit. This can either be done by a flag in one of the color attachments or by storing a special value in the depth or stencil buffer.
2. Render all primitives that don't need lighting after the illumination stage over the illuminated scene rendering.

Both options have their advantages/disadvantages. With a flag, it can sometimes be more efficient if you have large region that don't need illumination because you can skip these calculations in the shader. On the other hand, this solution might need more memory because you have to store this information somewhere. In the second version, you have to make sure that you still respect the depth buffer created while generating the gbuffer (otherwise they would not be hidden behind illuminated objects), which might be as simple as attaching the same depth attachment or quite complex (if the illuminated data is rendered directly to the backbuffer).

Comment: BDL, thanks, I think I will opt for the second. 10 minutes after I posted this, I realized I could forward render those meshes with a separate shader. My only concern is how they will look when mixed with the gbuffer fragments. I will post an update if I achieve something good.